# video shape recognition in real time

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry, pattern-recognition

I believe from common sense that video shape recognition problems (identifying shape of a moving object) is of natural interest in many real world situations. The process of identifying is understood as recognizing/finding one selected changing shape/signal among all the present shapes/signals. Ideally, it should be possible to track the shape.

I believe that this process (of recognising) might be computationally expensive (depends on the resolution). I would very much appreciate a survey level paper that summarises achievements so far.
It would be even better if the paper would point out to existing limits due to engineerical/hardware/technological restrictions. I am sorry that the question is a bit fuzzy.

Comment: No problem. I have deleted my own, when you have made edit. It is not perfectly clear to say "identifying is... identifying" but now it is quite obvious you want just tell objects apart with your object selected.

Comment: If you have your shape maybe Viola-Jones descriptors would fit?

Answer (score 1):

One standard approach is to use object detection / objection recognition / object localization on each individual frame of the video.  This means we can apply algorithms for doing that on a single image.  For speed, once you have detected an object in one frame, we can use object tracking to keep track of where it moves to in the next frames, and we don't need to use an expensive object detection algorithm on the next frame.  For instance, we might apply object detection on every 10th frame, and then use object tracking to track its motion for the next 9 frames.

That should give you enough keywords that you can search and find lots of information on each of those techniques.